# Excel different format for duplicate groups

Tags: excel, ms-office

Is there a way to format different duplicate cell groups(for example use different background color for each group).

In the table below I want cells `A1`,`A2` and `A5` to have the same background and `A4 and A6` another. `A3` will not have any formatting as it is not a duplicate.

Thanks,

```
   A 
  ---
1. 23
2. 23
3. 19
4. 42
5. 23
6. 42
```

Comment: How many different values would there be?

Comment: @mbratch I am working on a log file, I cannot tell how many would there be ahead of time. Each file will have different values. The one I am working on has 100 unique values and total number is about 550.

Comment: So to perform the scheme you want, you'd need to compute 100 discernible different colors?

Comment: technically yes, but I don't need 100 different colors. If I can use 5 to 6 different colors that should be enough. I am using conditional formatting using a single color but that is not helping me see any pattern when different groups of duplicates appear one next to the other like when a group of 23s come right after a group of 42s.

Comment: If there's usually enough of a spread, perhaps use conditional formatting in ranges of 10 or 16 values each. Anything more flexible than that will require VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This would be your code for formatting the cell:

```
Range("A3").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
```

and something like this to index the cells with repeated value

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim counter As Integer

counter = 1

for i = 1 to 'number of row
    Cells(i, 2) = counter
    for j= i+1 to 'number of rows
         If Cells(j, 1) = Cells(i, 1) Then
            Cells(j, 2) = counter
         End If      
    Next j
    counter = counter + 1
Next i
```

The second piece of code will give you a table that looks like this

1. 23 1
2. 23 1
3. 19 2
4. 42 3
5. 23 1
6. 42 3

based on the values in the second column you can choose what color to paint the first column